# Boat and Rock Problem: Is there a possible scenario in which the opposite will occur, in that the boat would decrease and the water level rise?

Tags: density, buoyancy

My question concerns the person in a boat with a rock brain teaser.

> You are in a rowing boat on a lake. A large heavy rock is also in the boat. You heave the rock overboard. It sinks to the bottom of the lake. What happens to the water level in the lake? Does it rise, fall or stay the same?

I know under normal circumstances the water level will fall, while the boat will rise.

Is there a possible scenario in which the opposite will occur, in that the boat would decrease and the water level rise? I think the answer is no, but I would like to see if anyone has any other thoughts about it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the rock with a helium balloon. What happens when you let it go and it floats away?